# Documentation for `*tmp*` in R?

Tags: r

While skimming through [the fuctions section of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) last night I came across this example:

> It’s often useful to combine replacement and subsetting

```
x <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
names(x)
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
names(x)[2] <- "two"
names(x)
#> [1] "a"   "two" "c"
```

> This works because the expression names(x)[2] <- "two" is evaluated as if you had written:

```
`*tmp*` <- names(x)
`*tmp*`[2] <- "two"
names(x) <- `*tmp*`
```

> (Yes, it really does create a local variable named `*tmp*`, which is removed afterwards.)

I have never seen the `*tmp*` used before and I'm not really sure what it is, how it works, or when to use it. I also can't find any documentation for it. I find the last comment – that it is removed afterward – to be particularly interesting because it seems that the ability to have variables that automatically remove themselves from the environment could be useful (if used appropriately). Also I have only been able to get this to work intermittently, which is somewhat unusual.

Does anyone know more about this magic `*tmp*` variable?

Comment: See section 3.4.4 of the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html).

Comment: Hadley should really provide references in his book ...